# Sacar una consulta sql de las siguientes tablas

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola buenos dias y espero vuestra ayuda. Necesito sacar de la tabla

restaurante:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

, de la tabla
usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y de la tabla tipo_usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

todos aquellos restaurantes que no pertenezcan a un tipo_usuario de id= 1 (propietario) en este caso es el 3 ( de nombre restaurante vacio), porque como podréis comprobar en la tabla usuario los id_restaurante de cada usuario es o 1 o 2 sobre todo los relacionados con el tipo_usuario 1(propietario)

Yo hace tiempo que toco poco las consultas

Comment: ¿Y qué intentaste?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    REST.nombre AS restaurante,
    USU.nombre AS usuario,
    TIPO.descripcion AS Tipo
FROM
    restaurante AS REST
INNER JOIN usuario AS USU ON REST.id = USU.id_restaurante
INNER JOIN tipo_usuario AS TIPO ON USU.id_tipo_usuario = TIPO.id
AND TIPO.id > 1
```

Nota: en el la condicion TIPO.id>1 puedes usar otras condiciones como NOT In o !=

Comment: me saca restaurante bendicho y restaurante momoa yo lo que quiero es al revés que me saque restaurante vacio

Comment: Aaaaaa entonces necesitas los restaurantes que no estén en la tabla usuarios?

Comment: quiero que me saque aquellos restaurantes que no pertenezcan a tipo_usuario 1 (propiedad)

Comment: Pues si te fijas bien el restaurante con Id 3 que es el "restaurante vació" no existe en la tabla de usuarios por lo cual jamas se te va a listar